# Search box animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a search box animation. when click on the icon, it opens. The problem is when I click on the "x" to close the box, it moves to right end first and then close. This is the link:`enter code here`https://codepen.io/BeauBo/pen/YxNwpp .
Anybody can help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It interferes with another class from "close.less" (I couldn't figure out where this css comes from). If you just rename your "close" class to something like "close-form", it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your search bar is being moved to the right is because your form is getting **float: right;** when the close button is pressed.

Add the following to your form.close class in your css to fix this issue.

```
form.close,
form.close .bar,
form.close .bar:before,
form.close .bar:after {
    float: none;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
```